# Problem milling with CNC function of Creality CP-01 3-in-1 3D printer

Tags: cnc

I am having a lot of trouble using the Creality CP-01 3D printer in doing pretty much anything, it doesn't seem to be compatible with any other software than the one provided which is extremely limited.

I want to perform my own milling operations, (this is a 3 axis machine, with X-Y on the table and Z on the head) but the software provided (Creality Workshop) can only accept JPG inputs. The milling depth is constant for any trace, and the carved dimensions are not to scale with the drawings.

I tried using Fusion 360 with multiple post-processor options, but the CP-01 printer seems to have a different G-code format. I tried Openbuild's online G-code generator, which was the closest but very poor calibration with my machine.

Not only that, but I am unable to carve PCB boards due to the lack of Gerber support, nor am I able to mill STL files.

Please advise on what I should do. If anyone knows a milling application that supports this printer's G-code or some other fix, please let me know.

Comment: software recommendation questions belong at https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: yes, either on SE.software.recommendations or on [SE.3D Printing](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/). If you don't get an answer on here (Robotics) after say a week or so, you may wish to ask on either of those sites. However, please do *not* [**cross-post**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/280335) (i.e. ask the same question on different sites simultaneously). You would need to first delete this question and then re-post it on a different SE site. Good luck! :-)